# Intermittently, in Spring JPA, modelMapper doesn't map @ManyToOne column

Tags: java, spring, jpa, mapping

`ComOrg.java`

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity(name = "com_org")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class ComOrg {
  @Id
  @Column(name="org_cd")
  private String orgCd;
  @Column(name="org_upr_cd")
  private String orgUprCd;
  ...

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "comOrg", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private List<ComTeam> teams;
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "comOrg", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private List<AuthUser> users;
  
}
```

It is ComOrg Entity. It is relationed with ComTeam, AuthUser, etc...

`ComTeam.java`

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity(name = "com_team")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class ComTeam {
  
  @Id
  @Column(name="team_cd")
  private String teamCd;
  @Column(name="team_name")
  private String teamName;
  ...

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "comTeam", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private List<ComStaff> staffs = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

It is ComTeam Entity Code.

`ComTeamDTO.java`

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@JsonNaming(value = PropertyNamingStrategies.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)
public class ComTeamDTO {
    private String teamCd;
    private String teamName;
    ...

    private String orgCd;
    private String orgUprCd;
}
```

It is ComTeamDTO code.

`AuthUser.java`

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity(name = "auth_user")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class AuthUser {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "user_cd")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer userCd;
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private String userId;
    ...

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "org_cd")
    private ComOrg comOrg;
}
```

It is AuthUser Code

`AuthUserDTO.java`

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Builder
@JsonNaming(value = PropertyNamingStrategies.SnakeCaseStrategy.class)
public class AuthUserDTO {
    private Integer userCd;
    private String userId;
    ...
    
    private String orgCd;
    private String orgUprCd;
}
```

It is AuthUserDTO Code

Finally, here is mapping method

```
public <S, T> T map(S source, Class<T> targetClass){
  return modelMapper.map(source, targetClass);
}
```

When I use `map` method, `ComTeamDTO`=>`ComTeam` can make `ComOrg` automatically.

But, `AuthUserDTO`=>`AuthUser` cannot make `ComOrg`.

Surely, `ComTeam` => `ComTeamDTO` and `AuthUser` => `AuthUserDTO` is working perfectly!

(get `orgUprCd` too)

And It occurs some method, too.

How should I change my code?